# Makefile error when building FreeBSD on OSX

Tags: macos, makefile, cross-compiling, freebsd

I'm on an OSX Box and I'm trying to build the FreeBSD kernel source. I've downloaded it by running

```
sudo svn co https://svn0.us-east.FreeBSD.org/base/stable/10
```

and then to test it I run

```
make buildkernel
```

however I always get the error:

```
Makefile:136: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

I've tried using bsdmake but I get:

```
Unknown modifier 't'
```

Have I skipped a step or am missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, to the best of my knowledge, building FreeBSD on another OS is not supported. However, building the *kernel* seems to be doable, since there is a Debian variant with a GNU userland running on a FreeBSD kernel. And cross-building FreeBSD for another architecture is also supported.

If your make is GNU `make`, that probably won't work. FreeBSD imported `pmake` long ago. (which on FreeBSD systems is just called `make`).

The build process depends on a couple of things;

- The source tree is in `/usr/src` (unless you set the make variable `SRCDIR`)
- The actual build is done in `/usr/obj` (unless you set the environment variable `MAKEOBJDIRPREFIX`)
- The build Makefiles use the "includes" in `/usr/src/share/mk`. So you should probably add `-I /usr/src/share/mk` to your make invocation.

You will also need a cross-compiler and other tools configured to produce FreeBSD binaries!

Then you might start with `make TARGET=machine xdev-build` to build cross-development tools. And then probably `make TARGET=machine kernel-toolchain`. This builds the parts of the system necessary to produce a kernel.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023, building FreeBSD on macOS and Linux is supported. The exact process is documented in the FreeBSD Handbook: https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/cutting-edge/#building-on-non-freebsd-hosts.